# Is there a way to find all comments by yourself on a specific users posts on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-search

So I have a situation where I am trying to find a particular image another user posted on facebook and I know I commented on this post/image a few times.

It was quite awhile ago and hence going through their feed isn't really all that practical.

So I know you can look at your "Activity Log" to find all comments you made for example, but how about filtering them by *user*; so you can see all comments you made to one particular users posts - or anything else that may help me find this post/image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Facebook search

`https://www.facebook.com/search/str/USER_1_ID/stories-commented/USER_2_ID/stories/intersect`

- `/USER_1_ID/stories-commented/` Retrieve posts you commented
- `/USER_2_ID/stories/` Retrieve posts by friend
- `/intersect` Find similar

Comment: What do you mean by user id? Do you mean an integer value? Not something like this: `bob.smith.77` ? As I tried that last format but it didn't work, but unsure how to get the user id.

Comment: Ok, I found an external service that helped me find my id; but perhaps you could provide info on this in your answer to help anyone else reading this out.

Comment: Ok...... once I figured this out, it *appeared* to work; but it doesn't appear to be showing everything, only a handful of things, definitely not everything.

Comment: @Brett Does switching the order of the search parameters change the results? i.e. `USER_2_ID/stories/USER_1_ID/stories-commented/intersect`

Comment: `It was quite awhile ago` I don't know the context of your problem, in general, the search works for me. It's not the supported way to do what you're asking for because there is no supported way to do it natively in Facebook.

`your mileage may vary and all that jazz`

Comment: @freginold Nope, just seemed like a bunch of interactions similar to the other method; not really the type of stuff I was trying to filter down to and certainly not all of it unfortunately :(